# Dom Language Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I am new to javascript and jQuery.

i just want to know that is there any way create something different ,say structured dom language ?

in jQuery to select all div

```
var divs = $("div");
```

i want to know the possibility of something like this

var SDL = new SDL();

```
var div = SDL.query("select div from document"); //or something like that ..
```

or to select a div with `ID`

```
var div = SDL.query("select div from document where id='divID'");
```

looking mad right ?

**i am sure i will not care about the downvotes for the question , but i need to know `why this is not good ?` or `why its is not posible ?`**

Please say something on this ...

Thank you.

Comment: Possible? Definitely. Good idea? Perhaps, it depends on why you need it. I don't think many other people would want it. What's wrong with `querySelectorAll` or an existing selector library (e.g. Sizzle)?

Comment: @JamesAllardice thanks .. i tried to study my friend who know sql well and who dnt knw anything abt jQuery ..the reason is just learn one language ...also i love to make write this code on server side...and render on client side as pure javascript .

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't need to know jQuery, you just need to know CSS selectors. There are not a huge number of them, and they are far less verbose than your example. For example, to learn enough to rewrite your example you simply need to remember that the `#` character means "ID" and then you get `div#divID`.

Comment: sure it is  ..but for somebody js is a second language ..also i would like to do something on server side ..

Comment: The DOM (document **object** model) is a very bad fit for anything SQL-like, which is designed for the **relational** model

Comment: well this makes the js files much more longer. every character in the js(filesize) file counts the performance of the whole application

Comment: yeah i got the points ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not good because it's pointless to implement or use. It would make the jQuery library much larger than it needs to be, and CSS selectors are clear enough anyway, as well as being far more concise.

It *is* possible, but what you're describing is actually pretty close to CSS selectors, but with a couple of extraneous words thrown in with some formatting changes.

In your "SDL" selector, it would simply be replaced by:

```
div#id
```

Why go through the trouble of writing a whole sentence to do the same thing? There may be a third party SQL-like selector library, in the same way [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) is a CSS selector library, however I've never heard or seen of one personally.

An SDL would also be much slower than using CSS-based selectors, as the string is more complex and has more garbage in it than a CSS selector string. More importantly, however, you wouldn't get the native speedups that `querySelectorAll()` *et al* give when used natively.

Comment: Still, there are many libraries with simple queries for DOM elements. I don't see the use-case for a more verbose language based on SQL.

Comment: @Markus I don't either. I think CSS selectors (especially with the jQuery extensions) are more than enough to do what is needed.

Comment: jQuery is good ,i know that its efficient for dom management.we are not against it,or we cant find some -ve of jquery ,i am just trying the possibility especially for who is familer with database

Comment: There might be a third party library somewhere, but I've never heard of/seen it personally.